# How to use dynamic DBContext as parameter in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am having few `static` methods that are repeated in multiple projects (`Multiple Solutions`) like below. Few Table structures are same in all projects.

Project 1

```
public static decimal GetBalance(string CustID, MyProj1Context _context)
{
    // My Line 1
    // My Line 2
    // My Line ...N
}
```

Project 2

```
public static decimal GetBalance(string CustID, MyProj2Context _context)
{
    // My Line 1
    // My Line 2
    // My Line ...N
}
```

I want to create a new `solution` with `class library` and reference new `classlibrary.dll` in both projects so I changed `_context` type to `dynamic` in `class library` as to work in both projects but it throws

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
> dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
> expression tree type.

```
public static decimal GetBalance(string CustID, dynamic _context)
{
    // My Line 1
    // My Line 2
    // My Line ...N
}
```

Is there any alternative way to use `dynamic DBContext` as `parameter`?

Comment: try `var` in place of `dynamic`

Comment: `dynamic` means the type is resolved at runtime instead of at compile time and is generally something you would want to avoid using

Comment: I think you could try to create a ContextFactory, in this factory, you could create DBContext based on the connection string. Then, when you call this factory, just tell the factory which database you want to use, then, it will return the DB context, and you could get data from the DB context. Please refer to the following threads: [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886430/) and [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063745/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using type arguments? And if you want to get rid of `static` you can do this:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    decimal GetBalance<TContext>(string customerId, TContext dbContext) where TContext : DbContext;
}

internal class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public decimal GetBalance<TContext>(string customerId, TContext dbContext) where TContext : DbContext
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I also would avoid directly referincing dlls in other projects. Dlls have no version, and this makes bugtracking difficult.

Try to use nuget packages instead. That's what they're meant for when consuming code from other solutions.

- You can upload your package to nuget.org, but you only want to do this for packages that benefit the community.
- You can upload your package to your github feed. I think you can make your package private
- Or, what I would recommend in your use case, is to place the package on your disk in a common location or on a server in the network. Install the package in your target project.

  - You can then even add a `nuget.config` to your target project which specifies your custom nuget feed (you point to the network folder where they reside) and any collegue will still be able to open your project rightaway

Comment: `'TContext' does not contain a definition for 'MyTable' and no accessible extension method 'MyTable' accepting a first argument of type 'TContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Here `MyTable` is added at Derived class of `DBContext`.